# How to debug "syntax error in conditional expression" in Bash?

Tags: bash, terminal

I am writing a Bash script and I am new to it. When I run it I get this error:

```
./greet: line 14: syntax error in conditional expression

./greet: line 15: syntax error near `then'
./greet: line 15: `   then '
```

The lines of code its throwing on are these:

```
if [[ $hour -lt 0 || $hour -gt 23]]
   then
      echo "Please Enter a value between 0-23"
      exit 1
fi
#
```

I have tried putting spaces after the "then" and rewriting it multiple times.

Comment: Save yourself some trouble with [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net)

Answer (score 1):

In the `if` statement, you need a space before `]]`.  The `[[` and `]]` have to be their own "words" as defined by the shell, so surrounded by whitespace.